# AppStore rejected because of code obfuscation and selector mangling: none is done in the app

Tags: app-store

My iOS app has gone through multiple releases. I just added another feature (playing audio files using facebook audio360 tbe format), and the app got rejected with the wording:

> From Apple
>   2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata Guideline 2.3.1 - Performance
>
> We discovered that your app contains hidden features. Specifically, It
>   would be appropriate to remove all code obfuscation and selector
>   mangling from this app before resubmitting for review.
>
> The next submission of this app may require a longer review time.
>
> Next Steps
>
> - Review the Performance section of the App Store Review Guidelines.
> - Ensure your app is compliant with all sections of the App Store Review Guidelines and the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>     Program.
> - Once your app is fully compliant, resubmit your app for review.
>
> Submitting apps designed to mislead or harm customers or evade the
>   review process may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   Program account. Review the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>   Program to learn more about our policies regarding termination.
>
> If you believe your app is compliant with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines, you may submit an appeal. Alternatively, you may provide
>   additional details about your app by replying directly to this
>   message.

I am not performing "code obfuscation and selector mangling", has submitted an appeal, which was also rejected pointing to the same guideline.

I am using objective-c with some swift, Xcode 9, Product -> Archive -> Submit to App Store... Is it doing some obfuscation that I could turn off?

Comment: Ask them for more detail.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I have asked them repeatedly for more detail to no avail. Last time I offered to look at my source code and got an even dumber reply suggesting to remove any third-party images and text: my app has a single image I crafted myself, no references to any third-party.

Comment: We had to deal with similar lately. Very frustrating.

Comment: I don't see the point of your topic.  You aren't giving much information.  You are not even telling whether you are submitting an iOS app, tv app, macOS app or whatever.  You probably have one or more features that are not telling your users about.

Comment: Unzip your submitted ipa file, and examine all of the contents (images and text, etc.).  Run strings in your executable, and note all of the Objective C classes and methods listed.  Make sure they match 100% of those used by your source code.  Remove all 3rd party frameworks and replace them with your own source code.

Comment: @eight We are seeing the same problem -- received same rejection message. As we don't understand what specifically they're unhappy with we asked them to provide more info. Rather than provide us with info, they told us to contact DTS with steps on how to reproduce the issue. (How can we do this if we don't know specifically what they are unhappy with?)  The code is obfuscated but we've had obfuscated builds of multiple apps approved for over a year -- another app with similar obfuscation approved within the past 2 weeks.

Comment: @hotpaw2 What specific problem/issue are your instructions attempting to solve?  (Put another way, what is the *specific rejection reason* your instructions are attempting to resolve?)  If you can explain that, it will help me to understand.

From reading your instructions it sounds like you are saying: Apple now long allows the use of all 3rd party frameworks.  I highly doubt that is the specific reason for the rejection.  If so, that is strange decision for them to make and it would be kind for them to communicate that broadly (and also directly when apps are rejected).

Comment: It’s possible that a 3rd party framework is currently constructed in such a way that it violates Apple’s app guidelines.  Try removing them one at a time, and replacing with your own audited safe source code.  Or inspect inside them if you know how.  Also, re obfuscation, Apple’s previous approvals do not seem to set any precedent for future approvals of the same methods.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Its possible a 3rd party framework is the problem however, why wouldn't Apple be so kind as to provide a suspect symbol or some sort of specific problem for us to investigate. The strange thing is we're more than happy (and really want!) to fix the problem _if we knew what it was_.  As it stands however, we have no idea what is the actual reason for the rejection and only have vague smoke signals to work with.  Regarding, your suggestion to inspect inside of them if you know how... We can do this, we just don't know what suspect thing(s) to look for unfortunately.

Comment: How to look?  What to look for?  Those sounds like good separate new questions for stackoverflow.

Comment: How to look is not the question. What specifically to look for (I.e. what specific bad symbol(s) did they see in the symbols dump) would be helpful. But for some reason Apple does not wish to communicate this (apparently).

Comment: @eight we are facing same issue today, it would will be great help to us if you will share how you resolve the same.

Comment: Does anyone solve this issue? Hw can we find the mangled selectors by its name?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your audio playing feature is using a 3rd party framework which does use code obfuscation?

In any case, you can use the /usr/bin/nm tool for outputting the symbols within your raw executable and see if any of those look "mangled" in any way.

Comment: Why would the use of "mangled" names be a problem?
 Been using name obfuscation as a primitive form of IP protection on iOS and Android for years without any app rejections on either platform.  Are you saying Apple no longer allows developers to use class/method names of their own choosing when submitting builds for review?  I would be floored if Apple has suddenly changed their policy and now requires specific naming schemes be used.. Flabbergasted if Apple now disallows the use of IP protection using name obfuscation (fairly standard practice for companies that care about IP).

Comment: There are news reports/rumors that Apple has discovered apps or libraries using certain forms of selector mangling to call private (disallowed) APIs.  It’s very difficult to prove that any mangling can’t potentially do that.

Comment: Interesting... this seems to suggest that maybe (maybe) the problem is they’re seeing a string in our app that maps to a private API on some version of iOS. So one strategy is: Step 1) Do the mojo to identify the private Apple interfaces and then step 2) do a check to see if any of those strings are showing up in our app/3rd party libraries. That’d also explain why Apple doesn’t want to tell us what they found as they don’t want to share the name of the private API string(s) hit.

Comment: @Chris -- could you expand on "do the mojo" part? How specifically I can check my app against all Apple interfaces?

Comment: @eight well, i was thinking the idea would be to either find one of the github repos that as has all the framework class headers dumped, or to generate 
all the class headers using class-dump (haven't done it yet, but I do think there are repos where this was already done)

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably a 3'rd party library that does that.

I used [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) to get to know the library.

First, unzip the ipa and get the app file.

Second, Drag it to Hopper and start scanning it.

Third, search for the mangled selectors.

Comment: in my case apple didnt mention any selectors or obfuscated code. Can you elaborate on how to search for mangled selectors?