# What kind of app code obfuscation is allowed by iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I realize that 100% code obfuscation is impossible, but I'm trying to prevent as much as possible someone from stealing a hybrid HTML Cordova / PhoneGap app by downloading the package from the app store and opening it.

I've seen a few posts that say their iOS app has been rejected due to code obfuscation, like this one:

[AppStore rejected because of code obfuscation and selector mangling: none is done in the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568675/appstore-rejected-because-of-code-obfuscation-and-selector-mangling-none-is-don)

Obviously, I don't want my app rejected so I am wondering what kind of obfuscation is allowed by iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1):

In Android, it can done by Proguard.

Follow this link for more details  - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProGuard for this but then take a look of Activities that use `AsyncTask`. Obfuscation and `AsyncTask` often results in NullPointerExceptions. Just for your information :)

Answer (score 0):

Google PlayStore has no rules that prohibit code obfuscation for Android, you can feel safe about this platform. As for Apple, they are much more sensitive to hidden use of undocumented APIs by selector mangling and code obfuscation. But speaking of Cordoba, there should be no problem if you protect the JavaScript code of your app (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57662061/192373).

You can find quite a few payed solutions for both Android and iOS if you search for "cordova obfuscation".

Comment: Does this mean that Apple prohibits obfuscation of code when submitting it to AppStore?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS to certain extent, Apple allows some obfuscation.