# Is Javascript code obfuscation allowed by the iOS App Store in Phonegap / Cordova apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, obfuscation, phonegap

I have seen some iOS apps (not mine) being rejected due to `“because of code obfuscation and selector mangling”`. I would like to obfuscate my Javascript code (using an online tool) of a PhoneGap web app. I know it's not great protection, but at least is something.

The question is, is this allowed or will it be rejected by the App Store? I don't want to go through unnecessary rejections and/or delays just because of obfuscating Javascript code.

I have suspicions that the selector mangling and obfuscation is only prohibited in deeper code level and possibly private API's, etc but I want to make sure.

If anyone has any advice, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be fine to obfuscate in this situation, but I do want to emphasize that it's arguably worse than doing nothing.

Comment: @coltonb Thanks for your reply. Why would it be worse than doing nothing?

Comment: Obfuscation is what is known as "security through obscurity." Experts unanimously (pardon my lack of citation, you may search the term if you're interested) agree it is not truly security, so you're more or less adding additional work (and stress) for no reason. I wouldn't bother with obfuscation and instead investigate how to better secure your app if you have legitimate concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is allowed. All my apps are minified/mangled and I haven't had any issue with either Google or Apple.